# C# stringbuilder + conversion

Tags: c#

What I have going on is this:
1) Reading a directory of files
2) Writing out to a text file the filenames + "|"
3) Where i'm stuck.....

I have a bunch of files named... and need to be converted corispondingly:
Apple0154~3.Txt convertedTO -> Apple0156.txt
Apple0136~31.txt convertedTO -> Apple0166.txt

The prefix is always apple so it kinda goes like:
Apple (always the same prefix).
The numbers match is # + ~ subnumber -1
always in in .txt

I'm sure this is confusing i'm using this code but i cant figured out how to get this resulting textfile:
  Apple0154~3.Txt|Apple0156.txt
Apple0136~31.txt|Apple0166.txt

```
{
            string resultingfile = ***This is what i dont know***
            string movedredfolder = (overlordfolder + "\\redactions\\");
            DirectoryInfo movedredinfo = new DirectoryInfo(movedredfolder);
            using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(movedredfolder, "Master.txt")))
            {
                foreach (FileInfo fi in movedredfolder)
                {
                    output.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(fi)+"|"+resultingfile);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: yes, this IS confusing.  what logic is used to determine that "Apple0154~3" becomes "Apple0156"?

Do I understand that you take the number after the ~ sign, subtract 1, and add that to the number before the ~ sign?

Comment: Static, I was failing the IQ test as well (-:. But the formula is in the question.

Comment: formulate is prefix <howevermany numbers> + <whatever after ~> -1

Comment: lol! Seven code snippets submitted so far. Must be Friday!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I see what you are trying to do.

Try using Regular expressions to grab the 2 numbers out of the original file name. Something like:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"Apple(\d+)~(\d+)\.txt");
Match mat = r.Match(filename);

if( !mat.Success )
{
    // Something bad happened...
    return;
}

int one = int.Parse(mat.Groups[1].Value);
int two = int.Parse(mat.Groups[2].Value);
int num = one + (two-1);

string newFilename = "Apple"+num.ToString("0000")+".txt";
```

Comment: I agree.  The first thing that came into my mind - Regex, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Shouldn't your regex be `Apple(\d+)~(\d+)\.txt` or am I a noob?

Comment: Even forgiving the missing backslash on the `d+` and the non-escaped backslashes throughout, this regex does not work as you have the wrong groups. And, to be completely pedantic, there is no method named `"parse"` on the `Int32` class.

Comment: @Jason: Fixed the Regex, and the lowercase p in Parse :-P but what do you mean about the wrong groups?

Comment: I'm going to look retarded if this is wrong, but I think if you compile and run the following `string filename = "Apple0136~31.txt"; Regex r = new Regex(@"Apple(\d+)~(\d+)\.txt"); Match mat = r.Match(filename);  Console.WriteLine(mat.Groups[0]);` you'll see `"Apple0136~31.txt"` on the console. I just took the first two lines of your code and added a definition of `filename` and a `Console.WriteLine` statement.

Comment: Error 2 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex' does not contain a definition for 'Groups' and no extension method 'Groups' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: I need to change Match mat = r.Match(fi) because this is in a foreach loop.   foreach (FileInfo fi in Files).   This direcotry can have klike 1000 files in it so i need to get all files.

Comment: i've got it changed horever i get the error int one = int.Parse(mat.Groups[0].Value); -> int one = int.Parse(mat.Groups[0].Value);

Comment: TJ can you tell me whats wrong with the regex it comes back when it trys to do the mat as wrong format

Comment: Should be: 
int one = int.Parse(mat.Groups[1].Value);
int two = int.Parse(mat.Groups[2].Value);

Answer (score 1):

Inside the foreach loop:

```
   string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fi);
   string[] parts = fileName.Split('~', '.');
   int basenum = int.Parse(parts[0].Substring(6));
   int offset = int.Parse(parts[1]);
   string resultingfile = string.Format("Apple{0:0000}.txt", basenum+offset-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

euh something like:

```
 string path = Path.GetFileName(fi);
 int indexOfTilde = path.IndexOf('~');
 int indexOfPoint = path.LastIndexOf('.');
 int length = indexOfPoint -indexOfTilde; 
 string tmp = path.SubString(indexOfTilde+1, length);
 int numberToIncrease = Convert.ToInt32(tmp) - 1;
 int baseNumber = Convert.ToInt32(path.SubString(5, indexOfTilde-4);
 string newPath = "Apple" + (baseNumber + numberToIncrease ) + ".txt";
```

and you can use the FileInfo.MoveTo for file movement :)
good luck!

edit: damn... too slow typing of me...

Comment: This is too brittle. It has too many magic constants and what not embedded in it.

Comment: sorry but i don't see why every answer needs a -1. ppl are trying to help out and everyone has it's own way and vision.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this should work for one file:

```
String filename = "Apple0154~3.Txt";
Regex re = new Regex(@"Apple(?<num>\d+)\~(?<add>\d+)");

Int32 num = Int32.Parse(re.Match(filename).Groups["num"].Value);
Int32 add = Int32.Parse(re.Match(filename).Groups["add"].Value);

Int32 rez = num + (add - 1);
MessageBox.Show("Apple" + rez + ".txt");
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it didn't assume that the prefix is always "Apple" and that the extension is always ".txt". No downvote, but no upvote either.

Comment: OK Jason, I am going to start an open source file renaming framework so we don't have all these "magic" constants!

Answer (score -1):

```
using (var output = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(movedredfolder, "Master.txt")))
{
    foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath))
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        var index = fileName.IndexOf('~'); 
        var firstNumber = Int32.Parse(fileName.Substring(5, index - 1)); 
        var secondNumber = Int32.Parse(fileName.Substring(index + 1)) - 1;
        output.Write("Apple0" + 
            (firstNumber + secondNumber).ToString() +
            fileExtension + "|"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants to know how to parse the numbers in the filename and combine using the formula he described

Comment: This is too brittle. It has too many magic constants and what not embedded in it.

Comment: Wow, so many sticklers today. Do you really think it makes a difference if I throw a couple `const` at the top? I didn't think so.

Comment: No, I think the preferred approach would be to avoid magic constants. Hence the regex answers.